# Item not removed from SOLR index after unpublish or delete

Tags: solr

When I delete or unpublish an item in Sitecore 9.1, it is removed from the web-database and sitecore_web_index, but not from my custom index (Solr 7.2.1), any other update finds its way into the index.

Since we use that custom index a lot (custom search, odata, most presentation controls), that is a HUGE problem.

Any thoughts?

All other updates like additions and changes end up in the index, only the deletions do not (get removed). I thought it might occur since the uniqueid isn't in lowercase, but changes work, so that would be very strange.

Config info:

```
<contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="cbs_index_web" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="core">$(id)</param>
        <param patch:after="*[@desc='core']" desc="rebuildcore">$(id)_sec</param>
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
          <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">

              <!-- DEFAULT SITECORE FIELDS -->
              <field fieldName="_uniqueid" storageType="YES" returnType="string"/>
              <field fieldName="_templatename" storageType="YES" returnType="string" />
              <field fieldName="_fullpath" storageType="YES" returnType="string" />
              <field fieldName="_language" storageType="YES" returnType="string"/>

              <!-- SHARED FIELDS -->
            ....    
          </fieldMap>
          <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>
            ....
          </documentOptions>
        </configuration>
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance" />
        </strategies>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
        <enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
        <enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

Comment: What index update strategy are you using on your custom index? Are additions and updates picked up as expected?

Comment: Can you elaborate on “custom index”. The details are important. What’s is the index configuration it uses?

Comment: Can you glean further information from the Crawling log? It should log incremental updates and deletions based on items in the Event Queue.

Comment: That's the problem... they do not (the deletions).